# SQLCMD does not print Rows affected in log file

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am calling stored procedure using SQLCMD which will insert data into multiple tables. And output of that procedure is captured in log file using `-o`. But, i can't see **Row(s) affected** any where in the log file. And same when I am executing procedure I am getting **Row(s) affected**.

Is there any other way to print **Row(s) affected** in log file along with print statement. I have tried using `SET NOCOUNT OFF` as well but no use.

Comment: Have you tried -Q "SET NOCOUNT OFF;EXEC YourProcedure"

Comment: Yes i tried with that too. Still i am not getting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but check your 'Connections' options for your Sql Server instance.

Using Sql Server Management Studio, right-click your instance and select 'Properties'.  Then select 'Connections'.  Under 'Default connection options', scroll down and make sure that 'no count' is **NOT** checked.

[image]